# CSS: Positioning of list-style-image

Tags: css, image, position

I have a list with `list-style-image:url("../images/prices/tick.png");`

How can I position the image correctly so that the image and the text are on the same `y` coordinate? Wasn't there a way to define it right after the `url` with `url("link") 20px 30px`?

I can't seem to find the info online on how it was done again.

Comment: Please post some `<!-- sample code -->` so we may better assist.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708833/adjust-list-style-image-position

Comment: There are no `list-style-*` properties that use `px`. http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/listproperties

Comment: It seems I confused it with the background: url. I really thought there was a similar property for list-style-image.. Now I understand why I couldn't find anything about it.. Thanks @ all

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're thinking about using a `background-image` rather than the `list-style-image`..

so set the `list-style` to none  and put a `background-image` on the `li`  - then yes you'll be able to position it a bit more accurately using the `background-position` part of this:

```
background: url("link") no-repeat 20px 30px;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this:

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
}
li {
    background:url(image.gif) no-repeat 0 0;
    padding-left:16px;
}
```

So background position and padding value could be configured.

Comment: Beat me to the punch! I was writing this exact method.

Answer (score 0):

Created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DJRKa/5/) for you to work with.  I adjusted the background image *position* so it would look more like a bullet.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mozilla's Developer Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/list-style) on list style, you cannot position the list marker using CSS.  The closest is list-style-position, which only lets you position the marker as inside or outside the list elements.

If you want to position the image, you're going to have to edit the image itself, or use the image as a background instead.