# <li> list-style-image + Select box, make Select box align to top

Tags: html, css

When I try to do `list-style-image` and a `select` box inside the `<li>`, the `select` box aligns vertically at the bottom, but the `list-style-image` vertically aligns at the top.  How do I make the `select` box also align at the top?

It appears the `select` box holds a `margin-top:5px` that i'm trying to get rid of, but its still there even when i set it to 0.

CSS:

```
  li { 
    list-style-image:url(image1.jpg); 
    vertical-align:text-top;
  }

  select { margin-top:0; }
```

HTML:

```
 <li>
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
 </li>
```

Comment: would using a background image vs a list-style-image solve your problem?

Comment: "margin-top" overrules "margin", so changing your css rule into: select { margin-top:0; padding:0; } should make a difference

Comment: @iddo i get what you're saying, but it doesn't solve this issue.

Comment: Hard to say what exactly causes the problem. You may try negative margin or bottom padding. But I think [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708833/adjust-list-style-image-position) gives a nice solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never use `list-style-image`. Instead, use padding an a CSS background. This is the only way you can control the image position properly.

Something like:

```
li {
  background-image:url(BulletCheck.png); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  padding-left:30px; 
  margin-left:-30px;
}
```

See my tutorial: http://preview.moveable.com/JM/ilovelists/