# Aligning <li> text to list image

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm making an unordered list to which I apply a custom `list-style-image`. It looks like this:

[image: My error list]

Where the list starts at the second line. As you can see, the alignment of the text to the list image isn't right. How can I fix this?
I've already tried with:

- padding
- line-height
- height

**CSS**

```
.formErrorList {
    margin: 10px;
    padding-left: 35px;
    list-style-image: url("/icons/minus.png");
    line-height: 120%;
}
```

None of these properties seem to have much effect.

Comment: Please post your style/html.. May be a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably just use a `background-image`.

Check this Q&A for more info: [Adjust list style image position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708833/adjust-list-style-image-position)

```
.formErrorList 
{
  margin: 10px;
  line-height: 120%;

  /* get rid of any bullets etc. */
  list-style-type:none;

  /* positioning is: 2px horizontal, 6px vertical. adjust to your needs. 
     you can also use keywords (such as "left", "top") 
     or percentages (eg. 50%) */
  background: url("/icons/minus.png") no-repeat 2px 6px; 

  /* pad to your liking */
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `list-style-image`, use `background-image` for `li`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TbvPD/)

CSS

```
ul li {
    background-image: url('http://indiapostarrow.gov.in/Writereaddata/bradcrum-arrow-icon.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-position: 0 8px; /* Change this according to your image */
                         ^ ^
                      /* X Y - Co Ordinates */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the suggestions to use a background image. To center it vertically, use 50% as the y-coordinate:

```
background: url(images/bullet.gif) no-repeat left 50%;
```