# Offset bullet image in UL

Tags: css

In my unordered list, I use an image for the bullet but the bullet appears aligned with the bottom of the text to the right of it. I would like to have it positioned in the middle of the text's height. Is there some way in css to center or add an offset to the bullet?

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
</ul>

ul
{
  list-style-image: url('/images/bullet_blue_8x8.png');
}
```

Comment: So that you can play around with it? Meaning you don't already know the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  background: url("/images/bullet_blue_8x8.png") no-repeat 0 -2px;
  padding-left: 18px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

You need to use `background-image`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `list-style-image` you can use `background-image` and position the bullet using `background-position` property.

Or if you want, you can also use `:before` pseudo

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4uAs8/)

```css
ul li {
  background-image: url(http://www.tandf.co.uk/journals/society/images/icon_pdf.gif);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background-position: 0 1px; /* X = 0 and Y = 1px */
}
```

Comment: @Itay he wants to position the `list-style-image`

Comment: @Itay also, you might refer something similar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708833/adjust-list-style-image-position)

Comment: I was only asking.. Anyway you're right.  What you did is probably the best way

Comment: @Itay yes, actually you cannot position the images right if you are using `list-style-image` so it's better to use `background-image` :)