# Can't line up bullets and text properly

Tags: html, css, list

Example:

[image]

At the moment I have it like on the picture but as you can see from those two small gray stripes, I used a textarea to make my bullets line out properly and still have the text lined up nicely.

Now I've been searching for a way to get the exact same result but without the text area because it's not supposed to be there.

Is there anybody who can help me? It's a school assignment which is why the textarea can't be there.

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML/CSS.

Comment: Check your `line-height` for the list. It might need to be adjusted since you have a custom bullet applied. Most likely, you'll need to adjust the line-height to the same height as your bullet graphic.

Comment: use a background image and background position. (And padding to move the text to the right)

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to demonstrate your effort. You should post the code you have and explain what you've tried. This isn't a free homework providing site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [adjust list style image position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708833/adjust-list-style-image-position)

Answer (score -1):

I can't really judge because you have no code, but if I were to guess, you probably need a text-indent on your `li` elements that is equal to the width of the `textarea`.

To clarify, your css should look something like this (assuming the width of the textarea is 20 pixels wide):

```
ul > li {text-indent:20px}
```

Comment: This is not the answer, this is a comment.

Comment: Text-indent will do nothing to vertically align the list image and the text.