# Padding bottom, text only in list

Tags: html, css, list

I have custom list-item marker for my list (ul). I want to make the text in the li elements to be higher up, but not the list-item markers. This, because I think it looks better.

1 is how it looks today, 2 is how I want it to look.
[image]

My code:

```
ul.list-ok {
    font-size: 16px;
    list-style-image: url('img/ok-18.png');
}

    ul.list-ok li {
        padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    }
```

How do I accomplish what I want?

Comment: look at `vertical-align`

Comment: To illustrate what Sanuel Jackson said: http://jsfiddle.net/bfp1jhtn/

Comment: vertical-align doesn't help, here are some nice answers... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708833/adjust-list-style-image-position

Comment: But using background image is much more flexible: http://jsfiddle.net/pxdh3byy/

Answer (score 0):

This is not the proper way but this would do the trick: [Jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ecghd908/1/)

```
ul.list-ok li:before {
    position: relative;
    top: -6px;
    right: 8px;
    content: url('https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/nuvola2/16x16/actions/camera_test.png');
}
ul.list-ok li {
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```