# How can i center vertical list style image?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am stuck, I want the list-style-image to be vertically centered on the text.

Here is the code:

```css
ul{
    list-style-image: url(http://www.html2responsive.com/right-icon.png);
  text-align: center;
  list-style-position: inside;
    
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>SMS/EMAIL Updates</li>
  <li>Practicle Opinion</li>
  <li>Prepration & Filling</li>
  <li>Trademark Control Panel</li>
  <li>Trademark Monitoring</li>
  <li>Free Search Report</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708833/adjust-list-style-image-position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would edit the `PNG` file itself and add a few transparent pixels at its bottom (or top, depending what is appropriate). I don't think there is a way to achieve that in CSS.

Comment: ...Or the top. It looks like they are too high.