# Adjust bullet image a bit - HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a page here: http://beaminggeek.com/profitbuilder/test-2/

Currently the bullets doesn't fit right with its item.

I have the ff codes:

```
    <div style="width: 75%; margin-left: 103px;">
<h3 style="color: #0f8cef; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 20px;">Let's Scale Your Business FAST!</h3>
<h3 style="color: #0f8cef; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 20px;">In This Masterclass, You'll Discover...</h3>
<ul style="list-style-image: url('http://beaminggeek.com/profitbuilder/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/bullet.png'); font-size: 18px; color: #555555; letter-spacing: 0.5px; line-height: 26px; margin: 35px 0px;">
    <li style="margin: 16px;">How to attract a CONSTANT flow of the PERFECT clients into your business every day...</li>
    <li style="margin: 16px;">Why LOW PRICES are hurting your business (and your client results)... and how to start commanding $3,000+ prices...</li>
    <li style="margin: 16px;">A PROVEN 4-step system for putting ALL of your client attraction on 100% autopilot...you won't have to hunt for clients again...</li>
    <li style="margin: 16px;">How to get STUNNING results for each and every client, and turn your business into a referral-generating machine...</li>
    <li style="margin: 16px;">Why 1-on-1 coaching is OBSOLETE...and how to get better results for clients in less than half the time...</li>
    <li style="margin: 16px;">How to take a prospect from "click" to "client" in less than 48 hours. No more sitting by the phone, waiting to hear back!</li>
    <li style="margin: 16px;">AND...how to do ALL of this without blogging, Tweeting, "branding", podcasting, YouTube-ing, or ANY of that other "marketing" stuff that leaves you drained and burnt-out!</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to make it look exactly like this:

[image]

You can use Chrome's inspector tool to check the bullet and check how to adjust it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust list style image position?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708833/adjust-list-style-image-position)

Comment: Nope. Nope. Nope.

Comment: If you look at that thread you will find all the information you need to position your images correctly.

Comment: @MatthewMatt instead of saying "Nope. Nope. Nope", how about you actually give it a shot? It does work.

Comment: @MatthewMatt I have given a answer with a demo... please check :) ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/41873061/3206762

Comment: @Omer you suggested the cleanest solution :) nice

Comment: Thanks @MaurizioBattaghini :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here i got a working version without list-symbols.

```
<div style="width: 75%; margin-left: 103px;">
    <h3 style="color: #0f8cef; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 20px;">Let's Scale Your Business FAST!</h3>
    <h3 style="color: #0f8cef; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 20px;">In This Masterclass, You'll Discover...</h3>
    <ul style="font-size: 18px;color: #555555;">
        <li style="background: url(http://beaminggeek.com/profitbuilder/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/bullet.png) no-repeat left top;
        list-style: none;
        padding:0 0 16px 30px;">How to attract a CONSTANT flow of the PERFECT clients into your business every day...</li>
        <li style="background: url(http://beaminggeek.com/profitbuilder/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/bullet.png) no-repeat left top;
        list-style: none;
        padding:0 0 16px 30px;">Why LOW PRICES are hurting your business (and your client results)... and how to start commanding $3,000+ prices...</li>
        <li style="background: url(http://beaminggeek.com/profitbuilder/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/bullet.png) no-repeat left top;
        list-style: none;
        padding:0 0 16px 30px;">A PROVEN 4-step system for putting ALL of your client attraction on 100% autopilot...you won't have to hunt for clients again...</li>
        <li style="background: url(http://beaminggeek.com/profitbuilder/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/bullet.png) no-repeat left top;
        list-style: none;
        padding:0 0 16px 30px;">How to get STUNNING results for each and every client, and turn your business into a referral-generating machine...</li>
        <li style="background: url(http://beaminggeek.com/profitbuilder/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/bullet.png) no-repeat left top;
        list-style: none;
        padding:0 0 16px 30px;">Why 1-on-1 coaching is OBSOLETE...and how to get better results for clients in less than half the time...</li>
        <li style="background: url(http://beaminggeek.com/profitbuilder/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/bullet.png) no-repeat left top;
        list-style: none;
        padding:0 0 16px 30px;">How to take a prospect from "click" to "client" in less than 48 hours. No more sitting by the phone, waiting to hear back!</li>
        <li style="background: url(http://beaminggeek.com/profitbuilder/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/bullet.png) no-repeat left top;
        list-style: none;
        padding:0 0 16px 30px;">AND...how to do ALL of this without blogging, Tweeting, "branding", podcasting, YouTube-ing, or ANY of that other "marketing" stuff that leaves you drained and burnt-out!</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Use the css style inside html tag is a realy bad practice. I reccommend to separate the responsabilities

Comment: I know but just fixed the example. In real version definitely style via css /sass

Answer (score 1):

You can do that simply through CSS

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  background: url(https://s27.postimg.org/mebz7s2lf/bllt.png) no-repeat left top;
  padding: 0 0 10px 30px;
  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.</li>
  <li>Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut</li>
  <li>Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

modify your css, expecially your `li` style:

```
    li {
       margin: 0 auto;
       display: block;
       position: relative;
       list-style:none;
    }

    li:before {
       width: 21px;
       height: 21px;
       background-image: url(http://beaminggeek.com/profitbuilder/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/bullet.png);
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
       content: "";
       position: absolute;
       left: -25px;
       top: 4px;
    }
```

You can adjust the space between bullets and text increasing / reducing the `left` value. Obviously is a generic css style that target all `li`, you must specify a class name for these elements