# CSS list style image position relative to list item

Tags: css, list, html-lists

I have used an image as my list style image for creating nice bullet points, however they are not correctly vertically aligned to the list item. I have played around with the margin and padding of the list items, but cannot vertically "correct" them. What do I need to do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can find your answer here [[Adjust list style image position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708833/adjust-list-style-image-position)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708833/adjust-list-style-image-position)

Position your image with the position properties `top`, `left` and then use padding to position them:

```
li {
  background: url(images/bullet.gif) no-repeat left top;
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 10px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! background: url(images/bullet.gif) no-repeat left center; worked also, and it positioned the bullet perfectly vertical!

Answer (score 1):

Try `background:url('image/path') left center no-repeat` in css part.