# Change Bullets in styled list in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass

I am trying to achieve this style in my `<ul>`:

[image: Picture - 1]

I have used the `list-style-image` in CSS, but, I a being able to align the text after image. How can I do that? Here is the picture of the current output:

[image: picture - 2]

Here is my code:

```
#engineering-features {
  li {
    list-style-image: url(../img/engineering/li.png);
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
}
```

There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708833/adjust-list-style-image-position) in Stack Overflow, the most upvoted solution in that question didn't solve my issue.

Comment: This is not CSS

Comment: Add image in pseudo element and using ```line-height``` or ```display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;```

Comment: @AlonEitan sorry. my bad. Its scss

Comment: Is there any way to reduce the image height and weight

Comment: *the most upvoted solution in that question didn't solve my issue.* --> you are required to consider *all* the answers

Comment: Can you explain _how_ the solution you refer to did not solve your issue? Merely stating that something is not a duplicate does not in itself make it not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some padding and line-height:
Change my values as what suits your layout.

```
li {
    list-style-image: url(../img/engineering/li.png);
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding-left: 30px;
    line-height: 31px;
  }
```

Comment: Allmost solved my issue. Still the text is a bit below the image. Is there anything I can do to move the text a bit up?

Comment: thanks man if it works then accept my answer, for text a bit up try to adjust the line-height. or check if there is any other margin is affecting the result. margin: 0;